# Easy way to check that something is a number w/ max 2 decimal places of accuracy?

Tags: php

I want to make sure the input is A)a number and B)has at most 2 decimals.
`$number[$i]=int(100*$number[$i])/100;`
I imagine there is a more efficient way to do this... any suggestions? (using PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '')
```

Comment: I just looked at the man (http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) ... I assume the `, '')` at the end is to keep the commas in the thousands places from showing up?

Answer (score 1):

Regexes to the rescue:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d+\.\d{2}$/', $number[$i])) {
   etc...
}
```

of course, now that regexes are involved, you've got [two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html), as the old saying goes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number[$i] = round((float)$number[$i], 2);
```